# "Свидетельствует в том, что" или "о том, что"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "свидетельствует в том, что" или "свидетельствует о том, что"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

свидетельствовать **что (устар.).** *Примечания к «Русской Истории» свидетельствуют обширную ученость Карамзина (Пушкин).*
2. **о чем.** *Задача у меня была самая скромная — рассказать хотя бы и незначительные случаи, свидетельствующие о талантливости и простосердечии русского человека (Паустовский). Труд работников науки в Союзе Советов оценен по достоинству, как о том свидетельствуют сами представители русской науки (Горький).*

См.: Пунктуация и управление в русском языке Д.Э. Розенталь

Answer (score 0):

Защищать, заступаться, выгораживать (словесно) значит ***свидетельствовать в*** пользу кого-либо или чего-либо. Такое же значение имеет выступление (в защиту или против) кого-либо, ***свидетельствующего в*** суде.

Свидетельствовать можно только ***о*** виденном и услышанном лично; свидетельствуют ***о*** чём-либо факты и документы.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу "**свидетельствовать в**"

У Даля есть такое:

**Свидетельствовать в чем** (с предлогом за), удостоверять, утверждать истину виденного, либо известного кому.

Из Нацкорпуса:

― Ты должен **свидетельствовать в истине смерти царевича**, если будет нужно. [Ф. В. Булгарин. Димитрий Самозванец (1830)]

В современных словарях не встречается.